# UNKNOWN: No handler for that command

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I have the check_task.vbs placed in C:\nsclient++\scripts on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

I defined in the NSC.ini a NRPE Handler like this:

```
[NRPE Handlers]
check_task=cscript.exe //NoLogo scripts\check_task.vbs $ARG1$ $ARG2$
```

In the commands.cfg the command is definde like this:

```
define command{
command_name    check_task
command line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADRESS$ -c check_task -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
}
```

When I run the following code in /usr/local/nagios/libexec it responds with "UNKNOWN: No handler for that command"

```
./check_nrpe -h Server01 -c check_task
```

What am I missing?

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/639991/nagios-nsclient-cannot-run-included-external-script